# Socket not working with URLRequest on my PC

Tags: sockets, haxe, openfl, urlrequest

This is my code:

```
var teste:SpriteOnline = new SpriteOnline(170, 90);
teste.load("http://www.marciofaustino.com/uploads/1/6/4/6/16464874/143987431_3_orig.jpg");
this.addChild(teste);

//Cria a instancia do jogador
new Player();

//Inicialização dos sistemas
Security.allowDomain("*");

new Network("localhost", 6789);
Network.instance.connect();
```

And it works perfectly on my friend's PC, but when I run it on mine I get a socket connection error because of `Loader.load()`:

> Network.hx:59: IO Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=true cancelable=false text="Connection failed" errorID=0]

I only get this socket error when I try to get the `Loader` to `load()` some `URLRequest` and it works fine on my friend's PC. What can possibly be wrong?